# "Wanted" followed by "for"?

Tags: prepositions

Can *for* follow *want* in a sentence? For example,

*I really wanted for it to happen.*

*I wanted for these products to be back in stock.*

In the first sentence, omitting *for* will be totally alright but for some reason, adding it doesn't sound wrong to me either. Can somebody shed light on this?

Comment: It certainly *can*, but maybe not in the way you intended: “He was wanted for murder.”

Comment: Oh well, I was going to clarify that. I know that use but I meant _wanted for_ in a non-criminal context.

Answer (score 1):

That *for* is the first part of the infinitive [*for...to* complementizer](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299%20%22for%20to%22%20complementizer).

In an infinitive clause, *for* marks the subject noun phrase and *to* marks the verb phrase.

- *It would be a social mistake [**for** you **to** leave before dinner].*

In the infinitive above, *you* is the subject and *leave* is the verb,  both marked by the complementizer.

The *for* part is usually deleted, though, especially if the infinitive has no subject noun phrase,
so teachers say that *to* is a sign of an infinitive. Actually, *to* is a sign of an infinitive **verb**. 
Since most infinitives lack subject noun phrases, for a variety of reasons, mostly all we see is the *to*.

- *Bill wants [**to** leave before dinner].* (*Bill*, the subject of *to leave*, deleted by [A-Equi](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf))
- *Bill considers Mary [**to** be brilliant].* (*Mary*, the subject of *to be brilliant*, raised by [B-Raising](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf))
- [***To*** be mistaken] is not the same as [**to** lie]. (both infinitives have indefinite deleted subjects)

... though *for to* does still show up in regional speech varieties and fixed phrases

- %*She wanted **for to** go to the dance.*

But the *for* is required if there is a subject and it comes at the beginning of the sentence, i.e,

- ***For*** Bill to leave now would be a mistake.
  but not
- **Bill to leave now would be a mistake.*

After *want* in standard American English, both raised and unraised infinitive subjects occur

- *She wants there **to** be a party tonight.*
- *She wants **for** there **to** be a party tonight.*

and consequently both are grammatical. Every verb is different.

Comment: Perhaps it's somewhat archaic, but there's also the use of "want for" to mean a need or a desire: "If you marry me, you'll never want for anything." Or, "He's such an amiable fellow that he'll never want for friends, wherever he goes."

Comment: Yes, that's a different, intransitive, sense of _want_, meaning 'lack, be in need of'; it uses _for_ to mark the thing that is lacking or needed.

Answer (score 0):

No, "for" can't follow "want" in that way in a normal sentence; only in dialect, archaic or poetic forms.

"I really wanted for it to happen" should be either: "i really wanted it to happen" or just possibly, "I really hoped for it to happen"… the difference becoming perhaps more clear when we consider how obviously wrong is "I really hoped it to happen."

In similar negative vein, is it obvious that if for no other reason than that "I hoped these products to be back in stock" will always be wrong, "I wanted for…" needs much thought?

Why "hope" and "want" must behave so differently escapes me but simple answers might be that one was French and the other German, or one Greek, the other Latin…